# Python. Ошибка при выборе ответа 4 в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Когда ввожу 4, то программа не просит нажать Enter и не закрывается, а сразу же пишет то, что находится в блоке else, то есть Unknown command. Type again
Помогите решить вопрос, ну можно еще укоротить код

```
answer1 = input ('y/n: ')

while True:
    if answer1 == 'y':
        while True:
            answer2 = str (input ('\nIf you want to exit type 4\n1/2/3/(4 close): '))

            if answer2 == '1':
                print ('1')

            elif answer2 == '2':
                print ('2')

            elif answer2 == '3':
                print ('3')

            elif answer2 != '1' or answer2 != '2' or answer2 != '3' or answer2 != '4' or answer2 == '':
                print ('Unknown command. Type again')

            elif answer2 == '4':
                input ('Click Enter to exit')
                exit ()
            continue
    elif answer1 == 'n':
            input ('Click Enter to exit')
            exit ()

    else:
            print ('Unknown command. Type again')
    continue
```

Comment: [пример реализации](https://ideone.com/I3T3wq) произвольного меню, задаваемого динамически в конфигурационном файле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение

```
answer2 != '1' or answer2 != '2' or answer2 != '3' or answer2 != '4' or answer2 == ''
```

легким движением [закона де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) превращается в

```
not (answer2 == '1' and answer2 == '2' and answer2 == '3' and answer2 == '4') or answer2 == ''
```

Выражение в скобках всегда ложно (все четыре условия не могут выполняться одновременно). Получается

```
(not False or X) => (True or X) => True
```

Т.е. исходное выражение всегда истинно, поэтому ветка `print ('Unknown command. Type again')` будет выполняться всегда (если не выполнятся предыдущие ветки). До следующей ветки `if` исполнение просто не доходит.

Правильное условие:

```
answer2 != '1' and answer2 != '2' and answer2 != '3' and answer2 != '4' or answer2 == ''
```

Короче на Python можно записать как:

```
answer2 not in {'1', '2', '3', '4'} or not answer2
```

Но лучше всего переместить эту ветку в конец и превратить просто в `else`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать так, заменить операцию проверки

```
elif answer2 != '1' or answer2 != '2' or answer2 != '3' or answer2 != '4' or answer2 == ''
```

просто на `else`

```
if input('y/n: ') == 'y':
    while True:
        answer2 = input('\nIf you want to exit type 4 \n 1/2/3/(4 close):\n')

        if answer2 == '1':
            print('1')

        elif answer2 == '2':
            print('2')

        elif answer2 == '3':
            print('3')

        elif answer2 == '4':
            input('Click Enter to exit')
            exit()

        else:
            print('Unknown command. Type again')

else:
    input('Click Enter to exit')
    exit()
```

---

Так же можно попробовать сразу задавать значения `int` при вводе цифры и сравнивать полученное значение. А попытки ввести слово обрабатывалось бы исключением `except ValueError` (этот вариант подойдет если пользователю предлагается только выбрать цифирный вариант значения)

```
if input('y/n: ') == 'y':
    while True:
        try:
            answer2 = int(input('\nIf you want to exit type 4 \n 1/2/3/(4 close):\n'))

            if answer2 == 1:
                print('1')

            elif answer2 == 2:
                print('2')

            elif answer2 == 3:
                print('3')

            elif answer2 == 4:
                input('Click Enter to exit')
                exit()

            elif answer2 > 4:
                print('Unknown command. Type again')

        except ValueError:
            print('Unknown command. Type again')


else:
    input('Click Enter to exit')
    exit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, все понял теперь

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы запрашивать ввод пока не получено `y/n`, выходя получив `'n'`. Затем,  запрашивая цифры на `'y'` и печатать их, выходя на `'4'`:

```
    [^yn]   ╔════════╗
  ┌──────── ║        ║
  │         ║ START  ║
  └───────▶ ║        ║ ─┐
            ╚════════╝  │
              │         │
              │ y       │
              ▼         │
    [123]   ╔════════╗  │
  ┌──────── ║        ║  │
  │         ║ DIGITS ║  │ n
  └───────▶ ║        ║  │
            ╚════════╝  │
              │         │
              │ 4       │
              ▼         │
            ╔════════╗  │
            ║  END   ║ ◀┘
            ╚════════╝
```

Можно определить `expect()` функцию, принимающую словарь ожидаемых ответов и соответствующих действий:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys


def exit():
    input('Press <Enter> to exit')
    sys.exit()


def expect_digits():
    options = {'4': exit}
    for d in '123':
        options[d] = lambda d=d: print(d)
    expect(options)


def expect(options):
    while True:
        answer = input('Input ' + '|'.join(options)).strip()
        if answer in options:
            options[answer]()
        else:
            print('Unknown command. Try again')


expect({'y': expect_digits, 'n': exit})
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Vs4rUo).

Для двух уровней вопросов, определять функции не обязательно, можно и напрямую циклы написать c простыми условиями (`if answer in ["1", "2", "3"]`). Использование `expect()` функции позволяет легко для бо́льшего количества вложенных вопросов расширить код.