# Несколько сменяющихся страниц inline-кнопок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, inline

Добрый день, коллеги. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.У меня есть много inline-кнопок. Для лучшего восприятия хочу сделать несколько что-то вроде страниц inline-кнопок с добавлением в каждую кнопок вперед(=>) и назад(<=), соответственно, чтобы можно было листать эти страницы вперед и назад. Одну страницу добавить не проблема, но как их разнести с возможностью листать не понятно.Прикрепляю часть кода. Заранее благодарю.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','help'])
def start(o):
      bot.send_message(o.chat.id,'Привет, воспользуйся кнопками меню!')
      keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
      keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Розн.Блок', 'Кор.Блок']])
      msg = bot.send_message(o.chat.id, 'Выберите блок!',
        reply_markup=keyboard)
def first(m):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Розн.Блок', 'Кор.Блок']])   
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Выберите блок!',
        reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m:True)
def name(m):
    if m.text == 'Розн.Блок':
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['Кнопка1','Кнопка2']])
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['Кнопка3','Кнопка4']])
              keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['=>']])
        msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id,'-----------Выберите кнопку----------',reply_markup=keyboard) 
    elif m.text =='Кор.Блок':
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id,'Нет информации')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def inline(c):
    if c.data == 'Кнопка1':
        bot.send_document(c.message.chat.id,open('Кнопка1.pdf', 'rb'))
    elif c.data == 'Кнопка2':
        bot.send_document(c.message.chat.id,open('Кнопка2.pdf', 'rb'))
    elif c.data == 'Кнопка3':
        bot.send_document(c.message.chat.id,open('Кнопка3.pdf', 'rb'))
    elif c.data == 'Кнопка4' :
        bot.send_document(c.message.chat.id,open('Кнопка4.pdf', 'rb'))
    elif c.data == '=>' : 
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name) for name
                    in ['Кнопка5','Кнопка6']])
```

Comment: Я тоже бота на телеграм делаю
На курсы какие -нибудь ходите?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, толковой информации не так много в рунете. В основном всю инфу беру из github и stack.

Comment: Может быть ,если бы был опытнее ,помог бы

Comment: какие действия вы выполняете при создании "страницы inline-кнопок" в первый раз? Что мешает повторить? (при условии, если нет встроенной поддержки в этом API). Для вдохновения, посмотрите как GUI wizard`ы реализуются (на html, pyqt -- что можете читать). Полезно знать о State шаблоне проектирования. Связанный вопрос: [Python state-machine design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2101961/4279)

Comment: Можно посмотреть несколько с другого угла. Чтобы позволить пользователю [ходить по иерархическому меню, можно использовать  Continuation Passing Style (CPS)](https://ideone.com/I3T3wq)

Comment: [вот пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811183/23044) для более простой варианта:  двухуровневое меню жёстко в коде прописанное.

Comment: У меня после создания первой страницы кнопок идет хендлер, который обрабатывает нажатие на эти кнопки и выдает соответствующий  файл. Следовательно, в этом хендлере нужно предусмотреть нажатие на кнопки => и <= далее и назад соотвественно. Я это сделал и как ответ на нажатие этой кнопки сделал вызов новой клавиатуры через inlinekeyboardMarkup , но к сожалению в действительности при нажатии на эту кнопку ничего не происходит, не понимаю почему.

Comment: @TimurNasyrov создайте минимальный пример кода демонстрирующий "ничего не происходит" проблему и обновите ваш вопрос. [mcve]

Comment: *"Прикрепляю часть кода"* -- не является равнозначным созданию примера как это описано по ссылке в комментарии выше (уберите ненужный код. Добавьте код, чтобы пример был самодостаточным. Добавьте *детальное* описание, что должно произойти и что вместо этого происходит).